# Is there a linguistic term for “grammatically well-formed word salad”?

Tags: semantics, generative-grammar

The accepted answer to [this question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/40305/34058) quoted Chomsky's (1955) famous “sentence” *Colorless green ideas sleep furiously* and an earlier example from Tesnière (1940s), which translates to English as *The vertebral silence indisposes the licit sail*. I understand that the point of these examples is to illustrate a distinction between grammar and semantics, which seems quite an elementary idea in linguistics. This set me wondering whether earlier authors had considered this topic, and whether there is a settled term for such constructions.

Lewis Carroll's poem *Jabberwocky* was grammatically well-formed, but the nonsense was in the individual words rather than in the composition of meaningful words. [Psychedelic poetry](https://www.poetrysoup.com/poems/psychedelic) might generate some examples, but (as poetry often does) tends to be careless of the grammatical rules of prose; and the author would presumably claim the poem to have a “poetic” meaning. One might expect Sokal's (1996) hoax article to be a rich source, but this is not the case according to [Steven Weinberg's analysis](https://physics.nyu.edu/sokal/weinberg.html) of it. So these are not good examples. Anyway, I am looking for an established term to describe a nonsensical construction that is valid in both the grammar and in the individual words, along with early examples from the linguistic or philosophical literature.

Comment: Conventionally, "word salad" is not grammatical, though it is a slang expression. You're looking for a word that describes it, not a phrase, right?

Comment: [Is this an example?](http://rubberducky.org/cgi-bin/chomsky.pl) It's all grammatical but it's got a definite salady feeling.

Comment: @user6726 :  I don't expect a single word for such a specific idea. The sequencing of two nouns to form a noun phrase (e.g. art form) is standard in English; however, I have no objection to adjectives (e.g. as in verbal salad) either. I don't agree that word salad is properly described as a slang expression. –

Comment: @jlawler : Your link doesn't work as supposed. But I was able to glean from it that you were referring to the *Chomskybot* program, and derivatives such as the *Postmodernism Generator*. These generate whole paragraphs of impressive-looking, and grammatically perfect, but subtly meaningless verbiage. All great stuff—but I wasn't able to find a term for the sort of sentence that they generate. Also, they are relatively modern (1990s).

Answer (score 4):

*Semantic anomaly* is the word you're looking for:

> Incoherent sentences that are not surface conjunctions of contradictory
> sentences do not so blatantly generate contradictory entailments. Indeed,
> their incoherence is often such that we are hard pressed to see that they
> have any entailments at all. Linguists have spoken of *anomaly* in cases like
> those illustrated in (64).
> (64)
> a. The square root of Milly's desk drinks humanity.
> b. Colorless green ideas sleep furiously.
> ...

(G. Chiercha & S. McConnell-Ginet, 1990, *Meaning and Grammar*).

Comment: Thank you. This citation is spot-on. An internet search for this term led me also to *anomalous sentence* However, my search didn't suggest that either term had much currency or focus on the sought meaning.